# Inflow sphere following path while pours liquid

Tags: fluid-simulation, path

my problem is that the sphere follows the path correctly but nothing comes out from it. I have tried with keyframes but it didnt work neither. I am not sure if it's possible but my idea was to write the word with liquid in case anyone knows another way to get it.

- Edit: Increasing the divisions from 32 to 64/80 worked for me but it will depend on your domain/inflow size.

Comment: Normally it‘s too low resolution of domain and/or too little inflow. If this does not help,please provide blend file

Comment: And also add your physics settings screenshot, @AFTERAPIOYoutube

Comment: I was trying 32 on resolution because my pc takes about 10 minutes for 64.  I don´t know how to increase the inflow. How can I upload the .blend? Wetransfer maybe? @Chris

Comment: please open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: Ok I'll post it in a minute (maybe more) when my pc finish the baking. @ChaudhryYousuf

Comment: 64 works but as I suposed my computer is burning. I've got a 1060ti with the ryzen 7 16gb ram, but baking takes really long. I guess I need more ram? [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=e9Xw2vnE" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/e9Xw2vnE/) @Chris

Comment: little tip: if you select the inflow and do "object" > set origin to geometry and set x/y/z to zero, the inflow will exactly follow your curve

Comment: Oh thank you! I don´t know why everytime I make some object follows some path the object change its position I don´t know why

Comment: nope. does not work with 64...by the way: If you "just want to know" whether it works or not - change the frame end in domain to something low like 20 so you don't have to wait that long... ;)

Comment: with resolution 80 i see something: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzMtj.png